# How to convert array of object using es6

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have this array:

```
const arr = [{field1: "xxx", format: "text", tags: [{id: 1, name: "test1"},{id: 3, name: "test3"}]},
 {field1: "xxx", format: "audio", tags: [{id: 1, name: "test1"},{id: 2, name: "test2"}]},
{field1: "xxx", format: "audio", tags: false},
 {field1: "yyy", format: "video", tags: [{id: 17, name: "test17"},{id: 22, name: "test22"}]}]
```

I would like to convert the above array so it's results should look like this using es6:
so basically each key should contain all unique values as an array

```
const res= [{field1:["xxx","yyy"],format:["audio","video","text"],tags:[{id: 1, name: "test1"},{id: 2, name: "test2"},{id: 3, name: "test3"},{id: 17, name: "test17"},{id: 22, name: "test22"}]]
```

Comment: So... what have you tried so far?

Comment: Also not sure why you want to use lodash for this. You can easily do this in plain js.

Comment: @Kielstra edited my question, how would u do it using es6?

Comment: Why a separate object for each key in the result?  That seems kind of pointless.  Everything could go in one object with a set of keys.

Comment: Also, your existing data structure is not valid Javascript.  You can't have an array that starts like this: `[11: {field1: "xxx", ...`

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arr = [{
    field1: "xxx",
    format: "text",
    tags: [{
      id: 1,
      name: "test1"
    }, {
      id: 3,
      name: "test3"
    }]
  },
  {
    field1: "xxx",
    format: "audio",
    tags: [{
      id: 1,
      name: "test1"
    }, {
      id: 2,
      name: "test2"
    }]
  },
  {
    field1: "xxx",
    format: "audio",
    tags: false
  },
  {
    field1: "yyy",
    format: "video",
    tags: [{
      id: 17,
      name: "test17"
    }, {
      id: 22,
      name: "test22"
    }]
  }
];

const DoThat = () => {
  const field1Set = new Set();
  const formatSet = new Set();
  const tagsSet = new Set();
  arr.map((data) => {
    field1Set.add(data.field1);
    formatSet.add(data.format);
    let t;
    if (!!data.tags.length) {
      data.tags.map((tag) => {
        tagsSet.add(JSON.stringify(tag));
      });
    }

  });
  console.log({
    field1: [...field1Set],
    format: [...formatSet],
    tags: [...tagsSet].map((tag) => {
      return JSON.parse(tag)
    })
  });

};

DoThat();
```

Answer (score 0):

We have an array of objects that we want to `reduce` to a single object. I would start writing this -

```
const result =
  input.reduce(merge, {})
```

Where we define `merge` as -

```js
const merge = (l, r) =>
  Object.entries(r).reduce(update, l)
```

Where we define how to `update` an object -

```js
const update = (r, [k, v]) =>
  Object.assign(r, { [k]: mergeValues(r[k], v) })
```

Which depends on us defining how to merge two values, `mergeValues` -

```js
const mergeValues = (l, r) =>
  isArray(l) && isArray(r)
    ? [...l, ...r].filter(Boolean)
: isArray(l)
    ? [...l, r].filter(Boolean)
: l && r
    ? [l, r]
: l ?? r
```

Which uses a readable alias, `isArray` -

```js
const isArray = x =>
  Array.isArray(x)
```

Expand the snippet below to confirm the results of `merge` in your own browser -

```js
const merge = (l, r) =>
  Object.entries(r).reduce(update, l)

const update = (r, [k, v]) =>
  Object.assign(r, { [k]: mergeValues(r[k], v) })

const mergeValues = (l, r) =>
  isArray(l) && isArray(r)
    ? [...l, ...r].filter(Boolean)
: isArray(l)
    ? [...l, r].filter(Boolean)
: l && r
    ? [l, r]
: l ?? r

const isArray = x =>
  Array.isArray(x)

const input =
  [{field1: "xxx", format: "text", tags: [{id: 1, name: "test1"},{id: 3, name: "test3"}]}, {field1: "xxx", format: "audio", tags: [{id: 1, name: "test1"},{id: 2, name: "test2"}]}, {field1: "xxx", format: "audio", tags: false}, {field1: "yyy", format: "video", tags: [{id: 17, name: "test17"},{id: 22, name: "test22"}]}]

const result =
  input.reduce(merge, {})

console.log(result)
```

```json
{
  "field1": ["xxx","xxx","xxx","yyy"],
  "format": ["text","audio","audio","video"],
  "tags": [
    { "id": 1, "name": "test1" },
    { "id": 3, "name": "test3" },
    { "id": 1, "name": "test1" },
    { "id": 2, "name": "test2" },
    { "id": 17, "name": "test17" },
    { "id": 22, "name": "test22" }
  ]
}
```